# In AR.js When Load Model ,Show A Loading Screen

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js, jsartoolkit

When We Load A Big 3D Model Or Big A Video, It Takes Time To Load The Assets(Resources) And Render The Resources,So I Want To Show A Loading Screen Or Loading Gif File or a Loading A-Box - Till The Whole Assets Loading And Rendering Is Done,On The Screen Or On The Pattern.Please Go Through My [GLITCH](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/676dab30-266d-438d-944a-43b616d08943) , Its Working But It Will Take 10-15 Sec to load and render.

I tried To Add Asset Loading Manager But It didn't Worked . I Tried All The Ways But It Didn't Worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Hello!</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.7.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v6.0.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@5.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" artoolkit='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; maxDetectionRate: 90;' arjs='debugUIEnabled: false;detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;'>
         <a-assets>
            <a-entity src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a5ca03d3-3024-44dc-9256-0b75c4247613%2Fscene.gltf?v=1563255364433" id="model"></a-entity>
         </a-assets>
         <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-entity  gltf-model="#model" material='transparent:true;shader:flat;side:double;metelness:2' scale="0.04 0.04 0.04" ></a-entity>
         </a-marker>
         <a-entity camera></a-entity>
         <a-entity shadow="cast: true"></a-entity>
      </a-scene>
      <script>
         // Workaround for an AR.js bug (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/410)
         const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
         sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', () => {
           sceneEl.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
           scene.add( camera );
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

After Showing The [HIRO](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Pattern-hiro.png) Pattern Its Takes 10-15 Seconds (Depending Upon The Internet Speed) To Load And Render . I Want To Show Some Preloader Or Loading Screen Or Some [Gif Loading Image](https://www.montclair-hostel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/loading5.gif) To Display Till The Object (Assets) Loads Completely And Render And Disappear Once The Rendering And Loading Is Done......

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For models, you can use the `model-loaded` event:

```
<a-marker preset="hiro">
   <a-entity id='loadingEl'></a-entity>
   <a-entity gltf-model="#model"></a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

---

The `#loadingEl` could have a primitive box with a "loading" image, and when the model is loaded, you remove (the entity or its visibility):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
   init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', e => {
          document.querySelector("#loadingEl").remove()
      })
   }
})
```

Glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~stack-57051773).

---

The `<a-assets>` system have a `loaded` event emitted, you could use it for videos as well.

Comment: I Tried This but Its Not Working .....Can You Send Me a Sample Executed Code In Glitch Or Edit My Glitch ....

Comment: Thankyou but,I Tried This but Its Not Working.CanYouSendMeA Sample ExecutedCodeIn Glitch Or Edit My Glitch.                                                                                                    
<a-assets><a-entity src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a5ca03d3-3024-44dc-9256-0b75c4247613%2Fscene.gltf?v=1563255364433" id="model"></a-entity>
</a-assets>
<a-marker preset="hiro" foo><a-entity geometry="primitive: box" id='loadingEl'></a-entity><a-entity gltf-model="#model" material='transparent:true;shader:flat;side:double;metelness:2' scale="0.03 0.03 0.03" ></a-entity></a-marker>

Comment: glad i could help !

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for Aryan's glitch, use the Hiro marker and your 3d model - [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fluoridated-wholesale-aurora?path=index.html%3A44%3A7)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Hello!</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.7.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v6.0.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@5.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     AFRAME.registerComponent('loader', {
       init: function() {
         let loader = document.querySelector("#loadingEl")
         this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', e => {
           console.log('loaded')
           loader.setAttribute("visible", "false")
         })
       }
     })
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" artoolkit='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; maxDetectionRate: 90;' arjs='debugUIEnabled: false;detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;'>
         <a-assets>
            <a-entity src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a5ca03d3-3024-44dc-9256-0b75c4247613%2Fscene.gltf" id="model"></a-entity>
         </a-assets>
         <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-box id="loadingEl"></a-box>
            <a-entity gltf-model="#model" material='transparent:true;shader:flat;side:double;metelness:2' scale="0.04 0.04 0.04" loader></a-entity>
         </a-marker>
         <a-entity camera></a-entity>
         <a-entity shadow="cast: true"></a-entity>
      </a-scene>
      <script>
         // Workaround for an AR.js bug (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/410)
         const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
         sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', () => {
           sceneEl.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
           scene.add( camera );
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```